# pandas filtering lists with lists

Tags: python, pandas

how do I get all of the 'id's' whereby an element in the 'combo' list matches any element in the 'search' list?

```
# setup df
d = {'id': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5},
    'combo': {0: ['a', 'b'], 1: ['a'], 2: ['c', 'd'], 3: ['c', 'e'], 4: ['d'], 5: ['c', 'f']}}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

search = ['a','d']
```

the following works, but can I just get a list of id's as a 1 liner - instead of writing to the data frame

```
df['check'] = df.apply(lambda x: any(i in search for i in x['combo']), axis=1)
df['id'][(df['check'] == True)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df.loc[df['combo'].explode().isin(search).any(level=0),'id']
```

Output:

```
0    0
1    1
2    2
4    4
Name: id, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
out = df.id[pd.DataFrame(df.combo.tolist()).isin(['a','d']).any(1).values]
Out[61]: 
0    0
1    1
2    2
4    4
Name: id, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set()`:

```
ids = df.id[df.combo.apply(lambda x: bool(set(x).intersection(search)))]
print(ids)
```

Prints:

```
0    0
1    1
2    2
4    4
Name: id, dtype: int64
```